# How to create common xsd generated class among all packages

Tags: java, xml, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have written a `Office.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
```

```
<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />

<xsd:complexType name="Employee">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="entry_time" type="xsd:decimal"
            minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="exit_time" type="xsd:decimal"
            minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="Furniture">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"
            minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="quantity" type="xsd:int"
            minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Office">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="employee" type="Employee"
            minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="furniture" type="Furniture"
            minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I am creating another `Institute.xsd` in which I have includeded `Office.xsd` as below

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="Office.xsd" />

<xsd:complexType name="Institute">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:in" minOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="employee" type="Employee"
            minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="furniture" type="Furniture"
            minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I am using `maven-jaxb2-plugin` plug-in .. here is my plug-in

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>emp</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>Office.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>com.nuovo.employee.model</generatePackage>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>inst</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>Institute.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>com.nuovo.institute.model</generatePackage>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                            <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
                            <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                        </args>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                <version>0.6.4</version>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I am getting `Employee.java, Furniture.Java and Office.java` in both packages
(`com.nuovo.institute.model` and `com.nuovo.employee.model`). Not only in Institute.xsd, I have to use only `Employee` as `type` in another `xsd`s also in some `XSDs` i have to use only `Furniture` as `type` how do I make sure these classes not duplicated in other packages and how to make these generated classes(`Employee.java`, `Furniture.java` and `Office.java`) as common to other classes

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid duplicated classes with maven-jaxb2-plugin, you have to use [modular - aka *episodic* - schema compilation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Episodes), i.e. using *episodes*, and XML catalog(s) [referencing the XSD file(s) from Maven artifact resources](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Referencing-Resources-in-Maven-Artifacts). However, it is a [known issue](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/1) that this does not work with schema `include` but only with schema `import`. So either you change `include` to `import` in `Institude.xsd`, or use one of the two options mentioned on the [known issue](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/1)'s page:

> - Write the META-INF/sub-jaxb.episode file manually.
> - Write your own XJC plugin to generate this file without map="false". It's not hard, see com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.episode.PluginImpl.

Also make sure you upgrade your versions of the maven-jaxb2-plugin and jaxb2-basics, they are pretty old.